# tinydb search transform string to where query

Tags: python, tinydb

A tinydb search is done like this:

```
db.search(where('birthday').year == 1900)
```

I want to take user input as a string and pass it to `search()`

In other words: `"where('birthday').year == 1900"` becomes the above.

Is this even possible in Python?

ps. this is running purely localhost so I'm not concerned about security.